# SVG: Font spacing very different on Windows and Linux

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, cross-platform, rendering

I'm developing a webapp using D3 to generate charts. When I test the app on different OS and browsers the fonts are rendered quite differently. The biggest difference is generally between Windows and Linux (ubuntu in my case). The width of a text element is much larger on Windows which causes the text to look more bulky. I know that it still seems to be impossible to make the fonts look the same on all browsers and OS's. But when I look on other examples of the d3 website the problem doesn't seem to be as big as in my app, so there must be some kind of workaround.

This is how I currently set up my chart in javascript:

```
var chart = d3.select("#wrapper")
                .classed("svg-container", true) //container class to make it responsive
                .append("svg")
                .attr("id", "chart")
                .attr("version", 1.1)
                .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
                .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
                .attr("viewBox" , "0 0 " + WIDTH + " " + HEIGHT)
                .attr("width", "100%")
                .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
                .style("font-size", "16px")
                .style("font-family", "Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif")
                .style("font-style", "normal")
                .style("font-variant", "normal")
                .style("font-weight", "normal")
//              .style("letter-spacing", "0px")
                .style("text-rendering", "optimizeLegibility")
                .style("shape-rendering", "default")
                .style("background-color", background);
```

CSS:

```
.svg-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.svg-content-responsive {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
}
```

I tried out letter spacing but it didn't really affect the rendering between the different OS.

How can I minimize the difference of font rendering between Windows and Linux?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the same font on both platforms. Your font-family supplies three alternatives.

Comment: have you tried  `.style("font-family", "Arial, sans-serif")`, that is the line where the solution will be I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verdana is a bit wider-than-average sans-serif font, and windows-specific. By specifying it you're almost sure to get larger text on Windows (Arial would be narrower-than-average).

Anyway it's quite unlikely you'll find a font present by default both on Windows and Linux (all variants), regardless of differences in text rendering. Microsoft likes to use proprietary fonts, Linux likes to use open-source fonts. Just make sure your design can accommodate 10/20% width differences (font-size is an height measurement).

That, or use web fonts, but web fonts have their own drawbacks (limited coverage, longer loads, angry caped-users).